# Why is my SVG's fill color not changing on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, vue.js

I'm using VueJS to create an interactive map of Japan. I'm using an SVG provided by Wikipedia. My template is as follows (What's important here is the prefecture and region classes):

```
  <div>
<svg id="japanmap" class="nation" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <g fill="#FFFFFF" id="ground" class="nation">
            <g class="nation" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round">
                    <g class="region" id="hokkaido region">
                    <g class="prefecture" id="hokkaido">
                            <path d="M591 250l-1 6h-3v-9l6 -2zM620 271l-1 -11 -4 -7 -5 -1 -2 -5 -4 -1 -2 -5 4 -8 -1 -11 2 -3 8 -2 6 -9 3 4 2 -1 4 -9 6 -5 -9 -13v-7l7 -3 14 11 10 -3v3l7 2 6 -2 5 -10 -5 -24 2 -5 8 -4 4 -5 -1 -23 4 -8 1 -11 -3 -17 -8 -19 3 -10 -1 -6 2 3h5l6 -8 26 28 8 13 16 17 29 18 28 6 1 4 6 5h19l22 -27 2 5 -11 24v9l4 6 9 3 -2 2 2 -3h-6l4 13 6 6 5 1 6 -8 8 -1 -11 8 -1 7 -17 3 -2 6 -5 5h-5l-2 -2 1 -2 -2 -1 -4 6 3 2 -15 1 -8 -3 -15 8 -14 16 -8 14 -3 8v16l-2 8 -14 -12 -23 -8 -28 -18 -13 -2 4 -2 -16 8 -15 15 -4 -2 4 -1 -5 -1 -2 -6 -8 -7h-10l-6 8 -3 9 1 5 12 8 10 -1 10 12 8 4 2 3 -6 5 -4 1 -9 -4 -3 3v-5h-3l-2 5 -7 4v9l-8 3 -3 6 -8 -3 -2 -7 1 -9zM659 58l2 -2 4 1 2 5 -4 4 -4 -4zM653 45v-1l2 2 -1 9 -4 -10zM957 29l-2 -5h-2l-2 4 2 7 -1 3 -5 1 -2 8 -7 -2 1 7 -10 10 -1 4 -5 -1v3l4 1v4l-4 4 -4 -1 1 5 -3 -4 1 5 -3 7 4 1 4 -9 6 -1 4 -9 10 -9 3 -10 5 2 6 -1 15 -18 13 -9 9 -1 1 -4 -2 -3 2 -4 -5 -2 -6 2 -12 17 -11 3zM878 110l5 -6 8 -2 5 -6 3 1 3 -7 -11 3 -7 -5 -4 2 -3 11 -10 14v3l-13 15 2 7 5 -1v5l1 -14 8 -4 1 -6h3v-7zM910 136l11 -9 -4 -3 -4 3 1 2 -7 1v4l2 -1zM888 154l3 -5 -6 1zM878 157l2 -2h-4z"/>
                    </g>
                    </g>
                    <g class="region" id="tohoku region">
                    <g class="prefecture" id="aomori">
                            <path d="M613 358v-7l-4 -4 7 -8h5l7 -4 2 -16 -3 -5 3 -1 1 -7 6 5 4 -3 4 2 2 15 3 7 6 -3 -1 -4 2 -4 11 8 3 -2 4 -16 -4 -7 -6 6 -14 3 6 -26 17 12 9 -5 -3 31 3 14 4 11 4 -1 5 5 -6 7 -5 -1 -4 2 -2 -2 -14 10 -3 -2 1 -11 -5 1v-6l-11 7 -3 -2 -2 2 -7 -5 -3 3 -13 -1 -2 3z" />
                    </g>
    ...
    ...
```

I also have the following javascript which gets all prefecture class elements and applies a mouseover event listener that changes the fill color.

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Map",
  mounted: function() {
        const japanMap = document.getElementById('japanmap');
        const prefectures = japanMap.getElementsByClassName('prefecture')
        for (let i = 0; i < prefectures.length; i++) {
                const prefecture = prefectures[i];
                prefecture.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
                        e.target.style.fill = "#E74C3C";
                        console.log(e.target);
                });
        }
  }
};
```

The message gets logged to the console but the fill color of the element does not change.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original svg? It is a bit unusual that the paths are inside the <defs> element.

Comment: I haven't worked with SVGs all that much. Here's the link to the original. I'd prefer using it since it has Japan's regions and prefectures neatly labeled. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Blank_map_of_Japan.svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using Vue directives and you shouldn't actually be using Javascript DOM manipulations to achieve that.

Simply add `@mouseover="changeFillColor"` and `@mouseout="resetFillColor"` directives to the elements that should have their fill changed when hovered.

```
  methods: {
    changeFillColor(e) {
        e.target.style.fill = "orange"
    },
    resetFillColor(e) {
        e.target.style.fill = ""
    }
  }
```

Or using only one directive (`mouseover`):

```
changeFillColor(e) {
  e.target.style.fill = "orange"
  e.target.addEventListener('mouseout', () => e.target.style.fill = '', false)
}
```

Example #1: http://jsfiddle.net/dsngf6ec/

Example #2: http://jsfiddle.net/dsngf6ec/5/

Based on your SVG (had to edit it a little to make it work): http://jsfiddle.net/dsngf6ec/55/

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't work :/

Do you think it may be the SVG? : https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Blank_map_of_Japan.svg

I'd rather work with this one since it has all the regions and prefectures labeled.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but I didn't have time to look into this earlier. I've created an example using your SVG, which I added to my original answer. The Vue-logic doesn't change here, but I had to tamper a bit with the SVG. My experience with SVGs is very limited, but the issue seemed to be with the `clip-path` which original SVG used. I removed it instead and added `transform=translate(384 -1024)` to isles above blue curve to make up for that.

Comment: Please excuse me for the late reply. I checked out the JSFiddle and it totally works. Thank you for helping out!